# How to change default SQL dialect to Standard SQL in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Every time I write query using the `bq` CLI tool I have to specify `--use_legacy_sql=flase`. I need to configure this. Google's documentation on this states it must be edited in the file `$HOME/.bigqueryrc` but there is no such file. In fact I couldn't find the `.bigqueryrc` named file anywhere on the server. Please help me to save few seconds every time I write a query. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following comments conversation above - the file under discussion - `.bigqueryrc` - can be created (manually) and populated with "default" flag values as described at the [Setting default values for command-line flags](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool#setting_default_values_for_command-line_flags) BigQuery documentation.